# How to develope a UI in android studio which will support all screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-studio, responsive-design, android-constraintlayout

I am developing a login page in android studio but when i change my phone size from 5" to 4" or 3.5" screen size device my layout components are adjusting but components looks bigger/large and when I change size from 5" to 6.3" or 6.5" screen devices then the components in the layout looks smaller.
I want to develop the UI which will look fine and properly adjust with screen size not bigger not smaller.
and I have also avoided the hared values to components and used constraint layout for the same.
please help e out with this problem  to develop the UI which will look fine and properly adjust with screen size not bigger/large[This is the 5" screen UI where components are perfectly align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nIUD.jpg) not smaller.
[This the 4" screen UI where components are appearing bigger/large in size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R8qU.jpg)
[This is the 6.3" screen UI where components are appearing smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrEGV.jpg)

Comment: Why not do a search online? it's FULL of similar questions, answers, tutorial, guides...... https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities | https://blog.prototypr.io/designing-for-multiple-screen-densities-on-android-5fba8afe7ead?gi=2e348bee7027

Comment: gone through them but not getting answer for this . the thing which is mentioned there is about multiscreen layouts(single pane, two pane)but i want that the layout must fit properly within the smartphone screens. It should not look smaller or larger on different screen sizes . and i am not getting answer fo that .

Comment: So what you want is not possibile. Using "DP" will change dimensions according to Display Densities, but using "PX" will display things different according to number of pixels. Achieving "same external (from your POV) phisical dimensions using a meter" is impossibile to achieve because it depends of: how much pixels are and what display dimensions (Width*Height) are in physical units (meters/inches). So even if two displays have same Density they could have different Physical size (5" vs 6.9") so each pixel is bigger in the second one that means it has different size from your POV.

Comment: Ok got it sir thank you, Is it possible to create the single layout file which will support different screen sizes?and how?

Comment: Yes you can use a single XML layout file and use "layout_width="@dimens/widget_width" that gets "widget_width" value from different XML Dimens files ("res/values/dimens/hdpi", "res/values/dimens/xhdpi", etc...) according to which is current Display Density.